# Databricks Query return no results

Tags: sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I'm performing a query to a delta table in databricks I'm having some issues from the results, since it results on "no query results error", please review below the expalanation.

First query made

```
%sql
select Name_of_the_data_field,value from db.servies where Name_of_data_field = 'provider'
```

which does not returns any query, nonetheless when I use the query the other way around, it works. Please review below

```
%sql
select Name_of_the_data_field,value from db.servies where value= 'test provider'
```

I've literally copied the Name_of_the_data_field value got from the last query and perform the query again with no difference.

Also I've tested with other field names and it works on some field values, I know it is not a size issue since I've tested with bigger field names and it is working.

Finally the delta table is being created with an ETL that transforms an Excel file to pandas and then the dataframe is stored in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Already solved, the field name was wrong since the ETL kept a white space which was not being recognized from the result.